# Get torrent peer list with python

Tags: python, torrent

I'm trying to get peer list for specific torrent and I can't use python-libtorrent since it's only for Windows. There's an answer [for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791021/bittorrent-client-getting-peer-list-from-trackers-python) which seems to provide all the code needed to make an anouce request. Yet I always get "Wrong response length while anouncing" or "socket time out".
I'm defining payload like this:

```
    payload = {'info_hash': hash, 'peer_id': 'ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD',
           'downloaded': '0', 'uploaded': '0',
           'left': '1', 'compact': '0'}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: You probably also need to send `event=started`and `port=XXXX`. Also, using `compact=0` is obsolete and some trackers only accept `compact=1`.

Comment: @Encombe `event` is defined in the code and it's 2. `port` is being parsed from url. I did try to use `compact=1`, but this doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried to use WireShark and compare to a working client?  A hexdump of your and the trackers messages would be useful.

Comment: @Encombe tracker always return something like 1 random byte. At least what I am sure about is that it's different every time. Sorry I'm kind of newbie in this. I'm not sure how to send you my message hex dump because it prints as something unreadable. You can see it's structure in the answer to which I linked to at "udp_create_announce_request". About wireshark I did not, and maybe should.